# How to avoid spill on spark.read

Tags: apache-spark

I've got a dataset that I need to summarize and persist using Spark.

The data is stored in gzipped parquet on S3 and is sized 245Gb.

I'd like to make the process as fast as possible, however the first stage of reading the data is taking 12 minutes.

My cluster consists of 31 core nodes with 32 vCPU and 256Gb of memory each.

Looking at the Spark History server.

On the read stage, Shuffle Write reports 1935Gb which i'm assuming is the size of data in memory.

However, if i look at the list of tasks for that Stage - all have input sizes <= 137Mb.
Shuffle Write is ~1.4Gb per task, but Spill (Memory) is ~5Gb and Spill (Disk) is ~1.8Gb.

I don't understand why Spark is having to write data to disk at all ?

Comment: How large are your Spark executors?

Comment: you have to provide execution plan as well as your memory config values like `spark.executor.memory` , `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` and maybe memory fraction configs

Comment: dynamicallocation is true - so spark is setting up executors with 40 cores and Storage Memory of 96.6Gb (i guess that would be ~200Gb heap)

Comment: Dynamic allocation controls the number of executors not their configuration (memory x cores).